# What Evidence Do We Have For the First Mammal?

Tags: evolution

*Edited for a less broad question, I've retained my original question in the event anyone wants to try to answer it*

**Narrowed down question**

According to evolution we should all share common ancestors, straight to the very first cell. I am trying to find evidence for these ancestors. So therefore as a start, what fossil evidence do we have for the first official mammal to roam the earth? What was the defining moment and change from whatever it was before to a mammal?

---

**Original question**

I'm just doing some research for my biology class and I was wondering
what evidence we have for the elusive "change of kinds" question? And
for clarification, I define kinds as the branches of life (essentially
birds, reptiles, mammals, amphibians, fish, etc etc). Do we have
evidence for the common ancestors that link the vastly different
species we have? Because obviously a human, tortoise, jellyfish, and
say tarantula are vastly different, each their own distinct "kind",
but according to evolution there should be common ancestors and many
distinct species leading up to them. We all came from one thing. Man
and primates came from one thing. Mammals came from one thing. Where
do we get that distinct change of a kind, from say a fish to mammal?

There should theoretically be tens of thousands of in between links
and species that were what led to everything today, correct?
Therefore, we should have mountains of fossil evidence to support it,
yet from what I've researched I've found very lacking evidence and
generally just see posts insulting creationists and skimping the
question. So by asking the question myself hopefully I'll get a
legitimate and clear answer that is the truth.

Comment: Yes there is tons of evidence, including whole living groups of species as well as fossil missing links. Every time science finds one of these "missing links", though, creationists pop in and say "oh well what about the link between that and (other group)" - it's really quite frustrating. Try an academic source on evolution like https://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/home.php

Comment: We indeed have thousands (in fact, probably hundreds of thousands) of evidence. Note that fossil are not the only source of evidence for such common ancestry. We also have genetic data, phenotypic, biogenographical and geological data that all agree on the same general story. The question is very broad though and it is hard to know exactly what study you would like to hear from. You might want to have a look at [this post](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2057/demonstrable-and-repeatable-examples-of-evolution) who list to thousands of studies explained in lay terms.

Comment: For a short and easy introduction to evolutionary biology, you might be interested in having a look at [Evo101 by UC Berkeley](https://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/article/evo_01)

Comment: Because of the phrasing of your question (usage of the expression "change of kind"), you might want to have a look at [this related post](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2057/demonstrable-and-repeatable-examples-of-evolution).

Comment: I entirely understand the theory behind evolution and that's why I question it. You all have mostly disregarded my question. Microevolution is certainly proven, but do we have proof for macroevolution is perhaps how it should have been phrased? If we have hundreds of millions of years, we should see thousands of distinct "in-between" species that we do not have today. Where is the fossil evidence for that? Can someone give me a direct link?

Comment: I am voting to close as too broad. If you can somehow narrow your question down (such as asking for specific type of evidence for a species lineage), then I would be happy to vote to reopen it.

Comment: @Timble Can you please tell us more precisely what fossil you are looking for. If you can pinpoint to a specific fossil, we would be happy to try to look for evidence of such fossil. For example, would a dinosaur fossil answer your question? Would fossil records of early eukaryote answer your question? Would bacteria fossils answer your question? Would fossils of early mammal answer your question?

Comment: Alright, what is fossil record for the common ancestor that all mammals share? What was the very first mammal that all mammals evolved from?

Comment: @Timble Great! That's a question sufficiently well defined to be answered. If you can edit your post so that this becomes your question, we will happily attempt to find evidence of fossils of early mammals.

Comment: Please take no offense but when you say `I entirely understand the theory behind evolution`, I doubt this is in anyway true given the phrasing of your question. Note that as a researcher in evolutionary genetics, I would not have the confidence to say such thing as " entirely understand the theory of evolution" because it is such as vast field of knowledge. Also, the fact that you seem to consider fossils as being the only source of evidence make it feel that you don't understand the extend of methodologies by which we gather evidence in evolutionary biology.

Comment: Apologies. When I said that, I meant that I understand the basics of evolution. I understand the theory of it, things that are better suited for their environment tend to survive those that aren't, things evolve through natural selection. A single celled organism through random mutations eventually created life as we know it today. I didn't mean that I know all the ins and outs of it. My knowledge of evolution is purely high school level and relatively low, but I'm better trying to understand it. Thanks for being patient with me :)

Comment: I made an edit (feel free to roll back if you don't like it) and I am rectracting my close vote. Thanks. I shall come back to your question tonight (or at least in the coming days) if it has not been answered yet.

Comment: Remi.b alright great, thank you. And also in response to what you mentioned in a previous comment that I neglected to respond to... obviously other evidence is great, but if it's not backed up by physical fossils, in my opinion it means and proves very little. And I'm just saying, that logically, there should be billions of fossils of unknown species buried on earth from the "in-between" species that were in the process of evolving into the next great things.

Comment: @Timble Not all dead animals fossilized. In fact very few do. So don't ever expect a billion fossils! Early mammals were rather small and mainly restricted to areas that are less likely to provide good fossils. But don't you worry, I am sure we have at least a dozen of good quality early mammal fossils.

Comment: You should not be looking for Mesozoic mammal fossils, as they are already Mammals, defined by 3 small inner ear bones, derived from jawbones of their ancestors. You should be looking for synapsid mammal ancestor fossils. Things like Pelicosaurs and cynodonts. What you see here is a transition from slow moving early creatures to dog-like predators that were built for running, and likely homeothermic (and fur-covered), but not yet defined as mammals because they did not yet have the characteristic ear bones.  There are hundreds of these transitional fossils.

Comment: iayork I have looked at it, but I'm looking for fossil evidence. Very few of the the pages on that wikipedia bit had any fossils. The couple that did were blurry and grainy. Where did the discovery of these animals come from? How do we know they're the links in this tree? When I looked at the individual animal pages and even when I looked it up seperately, it was very lacking in references or history. I'm not opposed to believing it, I simply believe there should be more fossil evidence than there is.

Comment: That monotremes, marsupials and eutherians all share these three inner ear bones (hammer, anvil and stirrup that we learned in elementary school), then it is likely that the single species that gave rise to all mammals had these inner ear bones too. The transition from say Dimetrodon to this common ancestor was gradual, but there are lots of fossils in the synapsid lineage.

Comment: @Timble The idea that there is some sort of conspiracy over missing fossils is a lie that is commonly spread by creationists. Fossils are exceedingly rare. Nonetheless, there is ample evidence of gradual change over the synapsid lineage, leading to modern mammals.  https://www.fieldmuseum.org/fossil-non-mammalian-synapsid-collection-field-museum   http://www.truthinscience.org.uk/evolution-synapsids

Comment: Part of the problem is that defining the exact point at which a "change in kind" took place, or even whether it did take place, is essentially a human construct, while evolution is continuous.  Take for instance the people who say that birds are dinosaurs, denying that a "change in kind" took place.  Or even that all dinosaurs were one kind, rather than (at least) two distinct sorts (saurischians & ornithischians, IIRC).

Comment: @jamesqf To piggyback on this comment, consider something much more recent that changes over time and see how difficult it is to detect a change in time, for example, when was the first baseball game played? There are points in history where you can identify the first time "base ball" was mentioned in a newspaper, or the first team that charged admission to watch their baseball game. There are more recent times when modern rules came into effect (e.g., the 'dead ball era'). It's clear baseball is played now. It's clear baseball wasn't played in the far past. Saying "first" mammal is difficult.

Comment: @Bryan Krause: Or consider the evolution of the telephone, from a wooden box that hung on a wall, like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_telephone#Early_commercial_instruments to a flat rectangular box that you can hold in your hand, and which shows pictures.  But they're all "phones" :-)

Answer (score 8):

Obviously, it's impossible to point to "the" earliest mammal; dividing lines are pretty much arbitrary. However, a reasonable representative of a very early mammal or very late mammaliaform is [*Arboroharamiya jenkinsi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arboroharamiya), described in [A new arboreal haramiyid shows the diversity of crown mammals in the Jurassic period](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature12353), from roughly 155-160 million years ago.  That shows a number of fossils, including this quite nice one: [image]

The supplementary information shows some cranial features, including this:
[image]

A related species from roughly the same time period, *Haramiyavia clemmenseni*, had CT scanning done on this fossil mandible:

[image]

yielding images like this:

[image]

Similarly, the [euharamiyidans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euharamiyida) were either very early mammals or very mammal-like cynodonts, which are known from a number of quite nice fossils including these three (described in [Three new Jurassic euharamiyidan species reinforce early divergence of mammals](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature13718)):

[image]

Comment: Good answer +1. It would be nice to have an estimate of how old these fossils are.

Answer (score 0):

It is a mistake to think that there was ever a "first" mammal.  There were only animals that were more mammal-like or less mammal-like. To ask what was the first mammal is like asking who was the first tall person.  What is "tall"?  "Mammal-ness" is on a continuous spectrum just as "tallness" is. All we can do is acknowledge transitional forms like those mentioned by @iayork.